# Exporting training data for deep learning tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am trying to export training data for deep learning so I used ArcGIS Pro.

I use sentinel imagery and it exports just 2 or 4 images and these images not open.

I try to use 3 band composite google earth imagery also.

ArcGIS Pro exports more images but all of them are black and do not show the object.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also! I was attempting to view the exported masks and they were all blank. I was able to submit a help ticket with ESRI and we worked together to finally realize that the exported masks are blank in image viewers, but if you load the masks back into ArcGIS Pro the masks are visible. It turns out they are not blank, the data in the exported images is at a bit depth that does not play well with the image viewers I used. I was able to use the exported image chips and masks with a [Mask RCNN Implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) to train a model for detection of the item we were targeting.

The "Export Training Data for Deep Learning" is a very powerful tool, it would have been nice to know about the exported masks not being visible normal image viewing applications... Needless to say I felt dumb when I finally loaded the exported mask back into ArcGIS Pro and saw they were fine. I spent too much time trying to figure that one out!